# elisp の正規表現を使って'\n'を挿入したい

Tags: 正規表現, emacs, elisp

**やりたいこと**
以下のような文字列に
"1. mojiretsu 2. strings 3. 4 shoes"

elisp の正規表現を使って'\n'を挿入したい
"1. mojiretsu \n2. strings \n3. 4 shoes"

**試したこと**

```
(let ((str "1. mojiretsu 2. strings 3. 4 shoes")
      (regex "\\([0-9]\\.[^0-9]+\\)")
      start)
   (setq start (string-match regex str))
   (while start
     (setq str (replace-match "\\1\n" nil nil str)
           start (string-match regex str (1+ start))))
   (message str))
```

出力
"1. mojiretsu
2. strings
3.
4 shoes"

期待される出力
"1. mojiretsu
2. strings
3. 4 shoes"

Comment: `replace-regexp-in-string` を使う方法もあります。`(replace-regexp-in-string "^\n" "" (replace-regexp-in-string "\\([0-9]\\.\\)" "\n\\1" "1. mojiretsu 2. strings 3. 4 shoes"))`

Comment: ありがとうございます！